# IPython and 3D : draw simple and interactive scenes

Tags: python, 3d, webgl, ipython

I'm working on a little funny project, that draw a planet based on fractal generation. My project works under standard PyOpenGL call, but in order to make it more interactive, I wanted to export it on IPython Notebook.

I only work with some triangles, in cartesian coordinate system. Is there a way, as three.js purpose, to draw a really basic 3D scene based on some polygons in IPython notebooks ? I saw a lot of static plot library but nothing that looks like what I'm looking for.

PS: by interactive, I meen you can rotate the scene for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, take a look at [PyThreeJS](https://github.com/jovyan/pythreejs) which is meant as a bridge between Python and ThreeJS. The included [example file](https://github.com/jovyan/pythreejs/blob/master/examples/Examples.ipynb) gives a good overview how to port your code to PyThreeJS in an IPython notebook.

You can make it interactive by combining PyThreeJS with IPython [widgets](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets).

Comment: Such answer, much examples, very positive, wow ! :) Had just a trouble at installation, please underline that user must run "python -m pythreejs.install" to finalize installation. Thank you !